# Simple IF statement only returning code in ELSE

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a simple IF statement to return a string of text in the email template that goes out to a customer when the order is fulfilled in Shopify.

I'm using this:

```
{% if order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Third-party Courier' %}
TEXT for courier
{% elsif order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Rigid Crane' %}
TEXT for RIGID CRANE
{% elsif order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Articulated Lorry (w/forklift)' %}
TEXT for MOFFET
{% else order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Articulated Lorry (w/Crane)' %}
TEXT for ARTIC CRANE
{% endif %}
```

But regardless of how I do this code, it only ever returns the ELSE section.

I have another code to check that the "custom.delivery_vehicle_type" does contain the correct information when selected in the metafield.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be great!!

TVM
D

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `if` `elsif` `else` [here](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags#conditional-tags)

you can pass the condition to `else` directly you need use `elsif` and you code become:

```
{% assign vehical_type = '' %}
{% if order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Third-party Courier' %}
  {% assign vehical_type = 'TEXT for courier' %}
{% elsif order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Rigid Crane' %}
   {% assign vehical_type = 'TEXT for RIGID CRANE' %}
{% elsif order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Articulated Lorry (w/forklift)' %}
   {% assign vehical_type = 'TEXT for MOFFET' %}
{% else %}
    {% assign vehical_type = 'TEXT for ARTIC CRANE' %}
{% endif %}
```

and lastly use `{{vehical_type }}` like this where you want in bellow code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Onkar. I've tried it that way too. It still only returns the ELSE statement (I'd pasted the old code - I had removed the last line so it just reads {% else %}. The metafield contains the correct information because I can output it to text and returns the correct value, but for some reason the IF ELSIF statement will only ever return the ELSE statement. If I remove the ELSE section, it returns no value at all.

Comment: Are you sure `order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type` able to send the correct comparable string?

Comment: You need to print the value {{order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type}} to check it, it have value or not

Comment: It's definitely returning the comparable string, but whenever I try to use this in an IF statement, it will not return the code within the block. Even if I do a simple one like this: '{% if order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == 'Rigid Crane' %}
  {% capture email_deliverytype %}
    {{ order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type }}<br>
  
  {% endcapture %}
{% endif %}' it wont return the value

Comment: when you said it goes to `else` it means above code is comparable that why is enter into last else which become default if none of if is correct.

Comment: you need to `assign` the value and use it later into bellow code.

Comment: So, perhaps: {% assign handle = order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type %} and then call that in the IF statement? I've tried this as well - and that doesnt work either

Comment: update the answer, with `assign` usage, take look

Comment: I've tried your code with the Assign part - its still only bringing back the code in the ELSE section. In the test, the metafield has the value of 'RIGID CRANE' but will still only return the ELSE section 'TEXT for ARTIC CRANE'... i dont get it!

Comment: Did you test it on code part or just checking the value into metafields backend, need to make sure code render the value on actual postion. to output simply use and take look `{{order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type}}`

Comment: Yep. I've even put the {{order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type}} within the else section (knowing that's going to show) and it brings back the correct value of RIGID CRANE - but the if statement will still not work properly.

Comment: I am sure there was any extra space or something with value that prevent it from compare, you also tried with double quote whole comparing like this one `order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type == "RIGID CRANE"`

Comment: Yep. Tried it with the double quotes - same result. Really cant get my head around why this IF statement isnt working!

Comment: simple this is due values are not pass the compare test, there was any extra into values from the metafield. you can give a try with `value` also `order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type.value`

Comment: How can i test the .value result? how do I code that bit in to test it? (sorry, bit of a newb)

Comment: https://www.identixweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/shopify-order-metafields.png

Comment: can you please share the same values from the order, to make sure but happen into backend order section?

Comment: So I've just ran this code: test2:{{ order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type.value }}<br>
test3:{{ order.metafields.custom.delivery_vehicle_type }} and the .VALUE is bringing back nothing - so its that, that is the issue.

Comment: I'm using the SINGLE LINE TEXT metafield with the four options as the selections.

Comment: Are able to send the snapshots like sample shots from the order edit screen, for better understanding?

Comment: and metafied setting where you created it, single_line_text have not options as per my knowledge

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReD9L.png

Comment: Thats the backend set up for the metafield

Answer (score 0):

Onkar - this is the image of the metafield from the order section
[image: This is the metafield information]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Re8eCsNiNC-v create same order metafileds on test store and send the email from order and it send the correct value into email

Comment: https://prnt.sc/TS7dKfxG0l7G

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1tRncAk12JhS

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Cv6QptnwoYoY

Comment: I'm trying to do this on the 'Shipping Confirmation' email template which goes to the customer when the order is selected as fulfilled. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Any luck on this one? I've gone to Shopify direct, and they have basically said that they wont help with code changes in the notification emails.

Comment: Checked and confirmed it working fine on shipping confirmation, if you want I am look into it, then send an store request on my profile email address and I will check it for you.